# Compilation error due to final class Vault in Magento version before 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, object-manager, compilation, interceptor

I am writing a plugin on class `Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface`:

```
<type name=“Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface”>
   <plugin name=“mageworx_ordereditor_change_title_print_order”
           type=“MageWorx\OrderEditor\Plugin\Block\Sales\Adminhtml\Order\View\Payment”/>
</type>
```

In Magento before 2.2.0 class `Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault` 
has "**final** class Vault"
but after 2.2.0 the class is "class Vault"

When I launch the following command in Magento 2.1.9
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`
I get error:

```
Class Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault\Interceptor may not inherit from final class (Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault) in /home/zalescky/web/m219e/var/generation/Magento/Vault/Model/Method/Vault/Interceptor.php on line 7
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/bin/magento:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/bin/magento:23
PHP   3. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   7. Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
PHP   8. Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:188
PHP   9. Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Interception->doOperation() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
PHP  10. Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Generator->generateList() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Interception.php:100
PHP  11. Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Generator.php:70
PHP  12. Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Io->includeFile() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:118
PHP  13. include() /home/zalescky/web/m219e/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php:158
```

In my extension I want to write a plugin for each payment method, but the final payment method class doesn’t allow me to do this. How will it be better to cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Final method is concept in oops magento , It doesn't allows. You need to use Event observer or over-ridding way of implementation for payment method functionalities , you wish to customize.
URL : https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/
Let me know your feedback.

Comment: kindly follow above suggested steps and things will work.